# How to write this code without using 11 if-statements?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
if (progressBar1.Value == 1) { progressLabel.Text = "1%"; }
if (progressBar1.Value == 10) { progressLabel.Text = "10%"; }
if (progressBar1.Value == 20) { progressLabel.Text = "20%"; }
if (progressBar1.Value == 30) { progressLabel.Text = "30%"; }
if (progressBar1.Value == 40) { progressLabel.Text = "40%"; }
if (progressBar1.Value == 50) { progressLabel.Text = "50%"; }
if (progressBar1.Value == 60) { progressLabel.Text = "60%"; }
if (progressBar1.Value == 70) { progressLabel.Text = "70%"; }
if (progressBar1.Value == 80) { progressLabel.Text = "80%"; }
if (progressBar1.Value == 90) { progressLabel.Text = "90%"; }
if (progressBar1.Value == 100) { progressLabel.Text = "100%"; }
```

Comment: I like dreza's answer, if you wanted to make this code more efficient you could use `if..else if` rather than several `if` statements.  it would hit one, show it and exit the code until the next iteration of the code

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why can't you do:

```
progressLabel.Text = string.Format("{0}%", progressBar1.Value)
```

As @MNZ pointed out I potentially didn't answer the question exactly how the OP asked.  So here's a slightly modified alternative option:

```
progressLabel.Text = FormatProgress(progressBar1.Value, progressLabel.Text)

private string FormatProgress(int currentProgress, string progressDisplayed)
{
    if (currentProgress < 0 || currentProgress > 100)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Current progress is not in a valid percentage range of 0 to 100");

    if (currentProgress == 1) 
        return FormatProgress(currentProgress);

    return currentProgress % 10 == 0 ? 
              FormatProgress(currentProgress) : 
              progressDisplayed;
}

private string FormatProgress(int progress)
{
    return string.Format("{0}%", progress);
}
```

And a unit test to confirm:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    Assert.AreEqual("1%", FormatProgress(1, "0%"));
    Assert.AreEqual("0%", FormatProgress(0, "5%"));
    Assert.AreEqual("10%", FormatProgress(10, "6%"));
    Assert.AreEqual("80%", FormatProgress(85, "80%"));
    Assert.AreEqual("100%", FormatProgress(100, "90%"));
    Assert.AreNotEqual("75%", FormatProgress(75, "70%"));            
}
```

Comment: Although this code is not exactly same as the code in question. It must have an if satement to check if progressLabel.Value is one of 1,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90 or 100.

Answer (score 1):

Use a switch statement...

```
switch(progressBar.Value)
{
case 1:
progressLabel.Text = "1%"; 
break;

case 10:
progressLabel.Text = "10%"; 
break;

case 20:
progressLabel.Text = "20%"; 
break;

case 30:
progressLabel.Text = "30%"; 
break;
}
```

etc...

Comment: this would be more code than the if statements.  it wouldn't be shorter.

Comment: @Malachi indeed, but it does address the multiple condition evaluation that you pointed out in your comment to the question, and is more elegant than a bunch of `else` blocks.

Comment: that is almost a toss up, but I think I am going to have to agree with you on that @retailcoder.

Comment: Switch Statements are much more efficient than an else if. Else if statements force each if statement to be tested before finding the correct one. Case statements only test once. Plus it gives you more flexibility than drezas answer, although drezas IS much shorter.

Comment: @CodeSlinger and that's what got you my upvote ;) ...although it *is* overkill in this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (progressBar1.Value == 1 || progressBar.Value % 10 == 0)
    progressLabel.Text = progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";
```

Assuming that you are using a standard WinForms progress bar, you shouldn't have to worry about the progressBar.Value being <0 or >100.